# parse string with jsoup

Tags: parsing, jsoup

I have a string:

```
String HTMLtag="<xml><xslt><xhtml><whitespace><line-breaks>";
```

I want to get 5 strings: xml, xslt, xhtml,whitespace and line-breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
String html = "<xml><xslt><xhtml><whitespace><line-breaks>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
for (Element e : doc.getAllElements()) {
    System.out.println(e.tagName());
}
```

**Ouput**

```
#root   --> This is the root element that is created by jsoup, you can ignore it.
xml
xslt
xhtml
whitespace
line-breaks
```

**Edit**

```
String html = "<xml><xslt><xhtml><whitespace><line-breaks>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
for (Element e : doc.getAllElements()) {
    String tag = e.tagName();
    if(!tag.equalsIgnoreCase("#root"))
        System.out.println(tag);
}
```